# Sapcy 3.0 : can't add costum lookups for Lemmatizer

Tags: python, spacy, spacy-3

I used the code below to add custom `Lookups` to a custom `Lanuage` class:

```
def create_lookups():
    lookups = Lookups()
    lookups.add_table("lemma_lookup", LOOKUP)
    lookups.add_table("lemma_rules", json_to_dict('lemma_rules.json'))
    lookups.add_table("lemma_index", json_to_dict('lemma_index.json'))
    lookups.add_table("lemma_exc", json_to_dict('lemma_exc.json'))
    return lookups


def json_to_dict(filename):
    location = os.path.realpath(
        os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.dirname(__file__)))
    with open(os.path.join(location, filename)) as f_in:
        return json.load(f_in)


@CustomeLanguage.factory(
    "lemmatizer",
    assigns=["token.lemma"],
    default_config={"model": None, "mode": "lookup", "overwrite": False},
    default_score_weights={"lemma_acc": 1.0},
)
def make_lemmatizer(
        nlp: Language, model: Optional[Model], name: str, mode: str, overwrite: bool
):
    lemmatizer = Lemmatizer(nlp.vocab, model, name, mode=mode, overwrite=overwrite)
    lemmatizer.lookups = create_lookups()
    return lemmatizer
```

But when I instantiate the `CustomLanguage` there is no lookup table in `nlp.vocab.lookups`. What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lemmatizer lookups are no longer in the vocab. They're stored in the lemmatizer component under `nlp.get_pipe("lemmatizer").lookups` instead.

If your lemmatizer factory creates the lemmatizer like this, anyone loading the model will need to have these JSON files available or the model won't load. (The lookup tables are saved in the model, but your `make_lemmatizer` method just hasn't been written with this in mind.)

Instead, create a custom lemmatizer class that loads these tables in its `initialize` method and then your code would look like this to add a lemmatizer and load its tables once.

```py
nlp = spacy.blank("lg")
nlp.add_pipe("lemmatizer").initialize()
nlp.to_disk("/path/to/model")
```

Once you've run `initialize()` once for the lemmatizer, the tables are saved with the model directory and you don't need to run it again when you reload the model.

It could look something like this, which would also allow you to pass in a `Lookups` object to `initialize` instead if you'd prefer:

```py
class CustomLemmatizer(Lemmatizer):
    def initialize(
        self,
        get_examples: Optional[Callable[[], Iterable[Example]]] = None,
        *,
        nlp: Optional[Language] = None,
        lookups: Optional[Lookups] = None,
    ):
        if lookups is None:
            self.lookups = create_lookups()
        else:
            self.lookups = lookups
```